# edit user profiles from an admin account -- error

Tags: php

This is my self referencing form...

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

I want it to post the id (currently retrieved from Get, so that $_GET['id'] retrieves the id # from the address bar after the form is submitted.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" />`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<input type="hidden" mane="id" value='<?php echo (int)$_GET['id']; ?>'>
</form>
```

This will post you id with the form

Answer (score 0):

okay, i figured it out -- after form submission has to be $_POST not $_GET to retrieve

```
also, the  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $_GET['id'] ?>" /> mentioned above
```